# Magento 2 Product Layout updates for different attribute sets

Tags: php, xml, magento, layout, magento2

I'm relatively new to magento 2, I have developed in Magento 1 previously and I'm struggling with the new layout file structure in a couple of ways and would like some help to understand a few things if possible.

I have 2 completely different products and one has lots of options when buying the other doesn't so I want to change the layout structure to move elements around (short description, SKU, etc) to 'fill the gaps'. I have already edited 'catalog_product_view.xml' and changed the layout file to suit one set of products. I now need to change/add a file to edit the layout for the other products.

In Magento 1 you could add code like below to change the layout file per product. Not I Ideal but I have a small product base so would be manageable.

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/newlayout.phtml</template></action>
```

How do I do this or something similar in magento 2? I want to create a new layout file and then tell the product to use this:

```
catalog_product_view_newproduct.xml
```

Not

```
catalog_product_view.xml
```

Can I make this automatic based on Attribute Sets?

I've tried adding:

```
<move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" after="-" />
```

In the 'Layout Update XML' section of the product but this doesn't seem to work? Any ideas why not?

I feel I have not totally grasped the layout ideology if somebody could help in simplistic terms that would be amazing but any help would be great.

Thank you in advance.